# Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight App & HTMLAgilityPack dealing with missing elements

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

Using HttpClient with HtmlAgility pack in a Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight app.

I'd like to know how to manage an exception where an node/image isn't contained within a section of HTML.

For example, this is a snippet of the HTML I'm getting the info from.

```
<PARENT>
    <div class="game-c">
        <div class="boxshot">
            <img class="cover" src="http://cover_source" />
        </div>
        <h3 class="h3 white-c">Game Title ...</h3>
        <p>Game description goes here...</p>
        <p>...</p>
        <div class="cta-signedOut">...</div>
        <div class="cta-signedIn">
            <a href="https://link.to.store"> 
            <img src="gameImage.gif" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</PARENT>
```

I need the img src from the third div (cta-signedIn).  However, for certain dates the last two div's are commented out.  So the code looks like this:

```
<PARENT>
    <div class="game-c">
        <div class="boxshot">
            <img class="cover" src="http://cover_source" />
        </div>
        <h3 class="h3 white-c">Game Title ...</h3>
        <p>Game description goes here...</p>
        <p>...</p>
        **<!--<div class="cta-signedOut">...</div>
        <div class="cta-signedIn">
            <a href="https://link.to.store"> 
            <img src="gameImage.gif" /></a>
        </div-->**
    </div>
</PARENT>
```

Ideally, when these two div's are commented out, I would like to use my own image file which is located locally in /Assets/Images/Unavailable.png

And could you confirm that the following code would be correct to locate the info...

```
div.SelectSingleNode("//div[3]/a/img").Attributes["src"].Value;
```

Thank you.

27/03/2016 - Added following:

I'm using the following code, but it doesn't load the local image.

I'm trying the following, but it doesn't work...

```
var img = div.SelectSingleNode("div[@class='cta-signedIn']/a/img");
var img2 = ("/Assets/Images/storeLogo_unavailable.png");
if (img == null)
{
    newGame.StoreLink = img2;
}
else
{
    newGame.StoreLink = div.SelectSingleNode("div[@class='cta-signedIn']/a/img").Attributes["src"].Value;
}
```

Also, for some reason, this code executes very slowly.  Any particular reason for that?

Comment: *"Ideally, when these two div's are commented out, I would like to use my own image file which is located locally in /Assets/Images/Unavailable.png"*. Use your own image for what??

Comment: Ok, I assume you simply want to check for existence of the image and do some logic accordingly...

Comment: Sorry if I was vague in my original post.  Within the main page I have an image which is bound to the contents of the node above.  When the HTML has both 'cta-signedOut' and 'cta-signedIn' present, the image will be that of src within 'cta-signedIn'. However, in the second example, where the two 'cta' classes are missing, I want the image to be populated by one locally.  Hopefully, that clears up my questions.  Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply meant to check existence of the image and do some logic accordingly, then you can check whether `SelectSingleNode()` given selector for the image returns `null`. For example, assuming that `div` reference the outer `div` in your HTML snippet :

```
var img = div.SelectSingleNode("div[@class='cta-signedIn']/a/img");
if(img != null)
{
    //TODO: do something with `img`
}
else
{
    //TODO: use local image file
}
```

BTW, I suggested a *possibly* more meaningful selector in the snippet above. Element position index is commonly less meaningful.

Comment: Great code example, it works to get the correct image off the website.  However, how do I load the local file into img?

Comment: If you search, there are already plenty of such questions in SO (haven't tried any of them tho). This is one example : [Windows Phone 8 C# Load and Draw PNGs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356838/windows-phone-8-c-sharp-load-and-draw-pngs)